# How can i get value from selection box in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

```
                                <table border="1">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>
                                            SR No.<br />
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Name
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Address
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Area
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            City
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Contact No.
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Volunteer List
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Bird Namea
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Status
                                        </th>
                                        <th>
                                            Send SMS
                                        </th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($pager->result))
                                        {
                                    ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $row['InqID']; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $row['InqFromName']; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $row['InqFromAddress']; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $row['InqArea']; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $row['InqCity']; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php echo $row['InqContactNo']; ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                        <select name="volunteerSelect1" id="volunteerSelect1">
                                            <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select Volunteer</option>
                                            <?php
                                                $select="SELECT * FROM tran_ngovolent where ngovolentNGOCode=".$ngoSelectId;
                                                //echo $select;
                                                $result=mysql_query($select);
                                                while($rowBird=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                                {
                                                    echo"<option value=".$rowBird['ngovolentMobile']." id='volmobile'>".$rowBird['ngovolentName']."</option>";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php 
                                                $birdID=$row['InqBirdType'];
                                                $birdSelect="SELECT Bird_Name FROM mst_bird WHERE Bird_Code=".$birdID;
                                                $result=mysql_query($birdSelect);
                                                while($bird_name=mysql_fetch_array($result))
                                                {
                                                    $birdname=$bird_name['Bird_Name'];
                                                    echo $birdname;
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php
                                                $inqStatus=$row['InqStatus'];
                                                if($inqStatus==0)
                                                {
                                                    echo "<a href='index.php?id=".$row['InqID']."&status=status&page=".$pageid."' onclick='return confirmAction()'>Pending</a>";

                                                }else
                                                {
                                                    echo "Finished";
                                                }
                                            ?>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="button" name="SendSMS" value="Send SMS" onclick="smsNgo(<?php echo $birdID;?>,<?php echo "'".$row['InqFromAddress']."'";?>,<?php echo "'".$birdname."'";?>,<?php echo "'".$row['InqCity']."'";?>,<?php echo "'".$row['InqArea']."'";?>,<?php echo "'".$row['InqFromName']."'";?>,<?php echo "'".$row['InqContactNo']."'";?>);return sms()"/> 
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <?php
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="10">
                                           <?php echo $pager->show(); ?>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>      
                                </table>
```

In this Program i get value from database in my selection box. show this image
[image]

In first selection box i got perfect out put in my JavaScript but other one selection box value is null or empty Here is my JavaScript and Ajax code.

```
function smsNgo(birdno,address,birdname,city,area,name,contact)
{
//document.write(mobile1);  
var ngocontact = document.getElementById("volunteerSelect1").value;
//var ngocontact = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
 {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
   {
        //document.getElementById("smsStatus").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;; 
    window.open("http://localhost/goal_bird/admin/edit.php","_self");

   }
  }
 var url="http://www.****.co.in/sendsms.aspx?mobile=******&pass=******&    senderid=SMSIdea&to="+ngocontact+"&msg=Bird id is "+birdno+" "+birdname+" "+name+"     "+address+" "+area+" "+city+" "+contact;
document.write(url);
xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send();
setTimeout("location.href='index.php'",2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the volunteerSelect1 name unique by adding some db unique id with it. May be `InqID` in this case?

```
<select name="volunteerSelect_<?php echo $row['InqID']; ?>" 
    id="volunteerSelect_<?php echo $row['InqID']; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

From a glance, i can see the name="" for all the `<select>` tags are the same... "volunteerSelect1"

try using something like volunteerSelect[id] or volunteerSelect[]

The SAME thing applies to the id="" attribute, they are all using the same ID, this is used by javascript to identify a particular DOM item

However you cant use [] in the id try volunteerSelect_ID

That's probably the problem, the ID attribute

Comment: It would probably be better for the OP to use the `name` and `id` attribute correctly rather then mess around with the index of an element

Answer (score 0):

modify this `<select name="volunteerSelect1" id="volunteerSelect1">` to this

```
<select name="volunteerSelect1" id="volunteerSelect<?php echo $row['InqID']; ?>">
```

then this `<input type="button" name="SendSMS" value="Send SMS" onclick="smsNgo(<?php echo $birdID;?>,<?php echo "'".$row['InqFromAddress']."'";?>,<?php echo "'".$birdname."'";?>,<?php echo "'".$row['InqCity']."'";?>,<?php echo "'".$row['InqArea']."'";?>,<?php echo "'".$row['InqFromName']."'";?>,<?php echo "'".$row['InqContactNo']."'";?>);return sms()"/>`

to this
`<input type="button" name="SendSMS" value="Send SMS" onclick="smsNgo(<?php echo $row['InqID']; ?>,<?php echo $birdID;?>,<?php echo "'".$row['InqFromAddress']."'";?>,<?php echo "'".$birdname."'";?>,<?php echo "'".$row['InqCity']."'";?>,<?php echo "'".$row['InqArea']."'";?>,<?php echo "'".$row['InqFromName']."'";?>,<?php echo "'".$row['InqContactNo']."'";?>);return sms()"/>`

then this `function smsNgo(birdno,address,birdname,city,area,name,contact)`
to this `function smsNgo(inqid,birdno,address,birdname,city,area,name,contact)`

and finally this `var ngocontact = document.getElementById("volunteerSelect1").value;`

to this `var ngocontact = document.getElementById("volunteerSelect" + inqid).value;`

Basically, what I did that i added an unique identifier to each selectbox according to inqid. Then I call function smsNgo with this ID and select the right selectbox :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged this as jquery. so to get the value from select dropdown, you will use something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/vKdeD/19/)